# Websocket ruby app crashes after page reload

Tags: javascript, websocket, sinatra, eventmachine

I have a **Sinatra** app that uses websockets with **sinatra-websocket** gem. Its purpose is to send data to forms on other websites by using **Watir**. I use websockets to allow my users to insert capthcas and sms confirmation codes without losing Watir session.

So, user goes to this page https://secret-gorge-5083.herokuapp.com, fills out the form, presses red button and it redirects them to this page https://secret-gorge-5083.herokuapp.com/sending_out, where they can decide to what websites their data should go by pressing red buttons.

But if user reloads last page, it will first load without all the external files (with `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` message in js console) and, if you restart it once again, it will crash the app with `/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/em/connection.rb:266:in 'close_connection': eventmachine not initialized: evma_close_connection (RuntimeError)` logs.

I guess event machine isn't initialized because js file that initializes it isn't loaded after first reload (connection refusal).

Here is my code on **github**: https://github.com/lakesare/credits/.

Why is connection refused? How to deal with my app crashing critically?

Answer (score 0):

Figures out in my **credits.rb** I had these lines:

```
  connection.onclose do
    warn("websocket closed from credits.rb")
    settings.sockets.delete(ws)
  end
```

and I don't have `ws` variable - I renamed it to `connection` and didn't notice this one. So, every time when websocket connnection was closed, it met an unrecognized variable - thus crashing an app. I changed `ws` to `connection` and it works fine on reload now.